# Error displaying a list with Listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a public method in **DatabaseHelper.java** class like below:

```
public List<Presentation> getAllPresentations() {
    List<Presentation> presentations = new ArrayList<Presentation>();
    //
    //
    // some code
    //
    //
    return presentations;
}
```

In my **MainActivity.java** I have added this lines:

```
btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            List list = db.getAllPresentations();

            ListView l;

            l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<List>(this,R.layout.view_presentation, list));
        }
    });
```

BUT, something is wrong on the line:

```
l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<List>(this,R.layout.view_presentation, list));
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `List list` is already a problem. use generics.

Comment: what does `R.layout.view_presentation` look like? you probably need to implement `getView()` in your `ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems:

1. In the context of an anonymous inner class (like `new View.OnClickListener()`), `this` refers to the instance of the inner class. The `ArrayAdapter` constructor needs a `Context`, so you must use `MainActivity.this` instead.
2. The type parameter of `ArrayAdapter<T>` must be the item type. So in this case, it should be `ArrayAdapter<Presentation>`.

So:

```
    List<Presentation> list = db.getAllPresentations();
    ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Presentation>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.view_presentation, list));
```

Comment: @user3659691 I was editing the question :) how about now? if it doesn't work, please edit the question and post the compiler error. it's difficult to find the problem otherwise

Comment: "The type parameter of ArrayAdapter<T> must be the item type. So in this case, it should be ArrayAdapter<Presentation>" <- this

Comment: @matiash in the logcat its not giving me errors.. only the queries are displayed (for exp. SELECT * FROM presentations). this query is generated by the method getAllPresentations() .. now i want to display the list of this query in a other java class file. but it doesn't display anything. :(

Comment: @user3659691 are you sure the query is returning data?